# How to connect to Ldap server using java?

Tags: java, ldap

Please find my below code and Help me connect to LDAP.

My code below :

```
 Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
 environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
 environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://192.168.0.214:389");
 environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
 environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=estsecondary,DC=com");
 environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*****8");
 try {
     LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null); 
 }catch (AuthenticationNotSupportedException exception) {
     System.out.println("The authentication is not supported by the server");
 } catch (AuthenticationException exception){
     System.out.println("Incorrect password or username");
 }catch (NamingException exception){
     System.out.println("Error when trying to create the context");
 }
```

But I'm not able to connect. I'm getting "The authentication is not supported by the server".Please find my LDAP structure below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGBKJ.jpg)

Comment: Could you include the stacktrace from the exception you're catching on line 12?

Comment: It seems that the authentication type is not supported by the server. There are three authentication types, including 'none'. Here is more information about authentication types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/auth_mechs.html

Comment: The authentication is not supported by the server[LDAP: error code 8 - BindSimple: Transport encryption required.]

Comment: Can you add e.printStackTrace(); before  System.out.println("The authentication is not supported by the server"); and share the error stack?

Answer (score 0):

You comment this:

> The authentication is not supported by the server[LDAP: error code 8 - BindSimple: Transport encryption required.]

I assume that is the exception message.  It is telling you that the connection has been refused because you are trying to send the BindSimple authentication credentials over an unencrypted connection.

- You are using port 386 which is (by default) a non SSL port.  If you want to use this port, you could possibly tell JNDI to do TLS negotiation before you attempt to authenticate.  There is some [example code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/ext/src/StartTlsSimple.java) in the [JNDI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/ext/starttls.html).
- Another alternative may be to change the URL to

  ```
         ldaps://192.168.0.214:636
  ```

  and use SSL for the initial connection.

In either case, you will need to provide the appropriate keys / certs in a keystore.

A final alternative would be to configure the LDAP server to accept BindSimple credentials over an insecure connection.  But that is ... insecure ... and you would potentially be putting your infrastructure at risk by doing this.  Don't.